# Use a variable to name a class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, object

Suppose I want the following psuedocode to work

```
method generateClass(string name, <string,type>[] attributes)
       class name()
             //used like int a 
             //          char b
             attributes[0].[0] attributes[0].[1]
             attributes[1].[0] attributes[1].[1]
```

How would I do it in python?

Comment: How is `attributes` organized?

Comment: Create a new type using [the 3-argument form of `type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Comment: In my psuedocode that should be an array of tuples, but the implementation can take whatever arguments are convenient.

Comment: @IljaEverilä could you give a usage example? I'm not sure that I understand, but the documentation makes it look like that returns an instance of a class, rather than a class itself.

Comment: @Dr.JohnAZoidberg no, it returns a class object. Also you don't type attributes in Python, so your pseudocode doesn't really translate. Do you have some actual code to demonstrate your attempts to implement this so far?

Comment: From the documentation: `X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))` creates a new type (class) `X` with a single base class `object` and class attribute `a` that has value *1*.

Comment: I'm asking how to implement it because I wouldn't know where to start. from what I can see

       `class x: 

        x = type('ABC', (object,), dict(a=1))`

creates a class abc that inherets object.

Comment: @IljaEverilä great! could you implement multiple class attributes? can you leave the class attributes unassigned?

Comment: It seems to me that you should start by reading the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to get a grasp on basic concepts and things that differ from for example Java.

Comment: @Dr.JohnAZoidberg no, just `x = type('ABC', (object,), dict(a=1))` creates a new class. You don't use the `class` keyword in this context. You can create multiple attributes by adding them to the dictionary you are passing in. Python is dynamic, so you don't necessarily need to set them at class creation time. Leaving them unassigned makes no sense, they either don't exist or are assigned to something (even if that something is `None`).

Comment: Of course, what ever you pass in the dictionary used as namespace becomes the attributes. That includes functions.

Comment: @Dr.JohnAZoidberg This is well worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/172176